# Converting TAFC routines to TAFJ - LCCY Local Var

Tags: temenos

I am Converting `TAFC` routines to `TAFJ` where I have found the LCCY local Var in a function called like this,

```
CALL EB.ROUND.AMOUNT(LCCY,Y.FT.COM.AMT,"","")
```

As we shouldn't use these variable in `TAFJ`, I fetched the local `ccy` data from one of the packages.

I have tried like this way,

```
Y.LCCY = REC.COMM<CG.ChargeConfig.FtCommissionType.FtFouCurrency>  
EB.API.RoundAmount(Y.LCCY, Y.FT.COM.AMT, "", "")
```

I would like to know if anyone faced the same? If you have any better way to portray this? or this is just fine.